# Eventhandler does not fire when user control's button is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button from a user control and want it to notify my form when it is clicked. Here is how I do it. It does not work. Can someone tell me what is wrong with it?

In user Control

```
    public event EventHandler clicked;
    public string items;
    InitializedData data = new InitializedData();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    public DataInput()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        clicked+= new EventHandler(Add_Click);

    }


    public void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        items = textBox1.Text.PadRight(15) + textBox2.Text.PadRight(15) + textBox3.Text.PadRight(15);

        if (clicked != null)
        {
            clicked(this, e);
        }
    }
```

In Form1

```
    UserControl dataInput= new UserControl();
    public void OnChanged(){
        dataInput.clicked += Notify;
        MessageBox.Show("testing");
    }

    public void Notify(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("FIRE");
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: "It does not work" is not exactly a helpful description. Does it throw errors or end up in an endless loop? The first thing you should check is why your function raising the click event is itself registered for the same event. That seems wrong.

Comment: Okay, let me try another ways. I am really confused when using event and handler. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `UserControls` `Button` Click event should be assigned to `Add_Click`, I don't think you want to assign the `UserControl` `clicked` event to `Add_Click`

Try removing `clicked += new EventHandler(Add_Click);` from your UserControl and set the `UserControls` `Button` `Click` event to `Add_Click` so it will trigger `clicked` on you `Form`

Example:

UserControl:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler clicked;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // your button
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Add_Click);
    }

    public void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (clicked != null)
        {
           // This will fire the click event to anyone listening
            clicked(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // your usercontrol
        userControl11.clicked += userControl11_clicked;
    }

    void userControl11_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am using the same format as you did but it does not work.